# Markov-Chain Error: requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(22, 'Invalid argument'))

Tags: python, tweepy

I'm unable to solve the problem I get with this project I’m doing at my university.
I’m using »token-stream.py« from https://github.com/kappaloris/markrov-text-generator

I constantly get the following error:

```
File "/Users/daniel/Desktop/markrov-text-generator-master/token-stream.py", line 102, in <module>
  main()
File "/Users/daniel/Desktop/markrov-text-generator-master/token-stream.py", line 97, in main
  streamer.sample()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 398, in sample
  self._start(async)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 340, in _start
  self._run()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 280, in _run
  raise exception

requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(22, 'Invalid argument'))
```

Unfortunately I'm far from being even a beginner in programming, so it would be great if you could solve this problem »for dummies«.

Comment: Please post the complete error including the stack trace where it tells you in which file at which line the error occurred. At one of the places mentioned in the stack trace you have likely supplied an invalid argument, according to the error message.

Comment: i added the complete text of the error field

Answer (score 0):

The exception happens in `tweepy` and the linked code contains this part:

```
## API KEY SETTINGS
auth1 = tweepy.auth.OAuthHandler('YOUR KEY','YOUR KEY')
auth1.set_access_token('YOUR KEY','YOUR KEY')
############
```

This authentication information is used in the to set up the failing connection.

It seems like you have to replace these `'YOUR KEY'` strings with your authentication information. You should have a key and a secret, and those need to be specified in both calls.

Probably you didn't do that and therefore you can't connect.

Comment: unfortunately thats not the problem, i checked that multiple times, and also regenerated the tokens. and in streaming.py there is no place to enter any codes…